# Tomcat JNDI resource for Datanucleus (JDO)

Tags: java, tomcat, jndi, datanucleus

I have developed an application on Tomcat 7.0 that uses Datanucleus / JDO to access to a database. I currently have the JDO connection properties stored in the "datanucleus.properties" located in the application itself. The connection is working fine, but I would like to store the connection information as JNDI, to have it on the server and no longer in the war itself (I always have to replace the file in the war when deploying it remotely).

I tried the following:

1. Create a  in the web.xml of the application (jdbc/ConnectionDB)
2. In "Server.xml", I tried to add the following the context of my application

   ```
   <Resource name="jdbc/ConnectionDB" auth="Container" type="javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactory" /> <ResourceParams name="jdbc/ConnectionDB
   <parameter>
      <name>javax.jdo.PersistenceManagerFactoryClass</name>
      <value>org.datanucleus.api.jdo.JDOPersistenceManagerFactory</value>
   </parameter>
   <parameter>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionDriverName</name>
      <value>com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</value>
   </parameter>
   <parameter>
      <name>javax.jdo.option.ConnectionURL</name>
      <value>jdbc:mysql://localhost/TomcatTest</value>
   </parameter> 
   ...
   ```
3. I then try to create a new PMF with the following syntax:

   Context context = null;
   PersistenceManagerFactory pmf =  JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory("java:comp/env/jdbc/ConnectionDB",context);

When I run my application, I get a javax.jdo.JDOUserException: You have either specified for this PMF to use a "persistence-unit" of "datanucleus.properties" (yet this doesnt exist!)

I don't really understand what is wrong in my setup.

Regards,

Marcel

Comment: Marcel, I'm doing exact same thing trying to get datanucleus and tomcat and mysql to work all together. My issue is for some reason I can't get the eclipse plugin to work on my classes and I keep getting class not persistable exception. The same code works on standalone application. I'm almost sure I have issue with where to put orm files and so on, if you could help out by sharing your folder structure and xml files and deployment if would be a huge help. I have posted a question here but had no answers yet. Look me up and see my question. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

I finally found the solution I was looking for, I post it here, it might help somebody else:

1. Create a resource in "Context.xml" file of the server

   ```
    <Resource name="jdbc/SyncTestDB" 
     auth="Container" 
     type="javax.sql.DataSource" 
     maxActive="100" 
     maxIdle="30" 
     maxWait="10000" 
     username="root"
     password="mysql" 
     driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
     url="jdbc:mysql://localhost/SyncTestDB"/>
   ```
2. Create a reference to that resource in the "web.xml" file of your application

   ```
     <resource-ref>
      <description>MySQL Database Connection</description>
      <res-ref-name>jdbc/SyncTestDB</res-ref-name>
      <res-type>javax.sql.DataSource</res-type>
      <res-auth>Container</res-auth>
     </resource-ref>
   ```
3. And finally get a Persistence Manager Factory using the JNDI connection:

   ```
   PersistenceManagerFactory pmf;
   Properties properties = new Properties();
   properties.setProperty("datanucleus.ConnectionFactoryName","java:comp/env/jdbc/SyncTestDB");
   ```

Answer (score 0):

Read the javadoc for *JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(String)* and it is obviously not for passing in some JNDI data source string.

Read the docs for Tomcat and you will also see that specifying a datasource you do not provide JDO connection details.

You can equally specify a persistence.xml with that JNDI string for the "javax.jdo.option.ConnectionFactoryName" property. As per the JDO spec and DataNucleus/Tomcat docs then

Comment: Hello DataNucleus, I want to do exactly what you mention in your 3rd point. But the Datanucleus online doc is not exactly helpfull, I only found the following  "Another alternative would be to call JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory(jndiLocation, context); , hence accessing the properties via JNDI." I tried to store the JDO properties as JDNI in Server.xml, but that does not work...

Comment: Just specify the persistence properties (in a properties file, or via a Map) to JDOHelper.getPersistenceManagerFactory.